# facing an issue on sudo apt update Err:6 hsecurity.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release

Tags: ubuntu, updates, ubuntu-22.04

After installing ubuntu 22.04.
while typing sudo apt update shows 404 of Err:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release,

[image]
e[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mixed sources.list. You are on jammy but you have impirish sources.list.

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Remove all inside and paste this:

```
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main universe restricted multiverse
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```